# Background color for my button doesn't work for all buttons

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, hover

The final section that says "Cardio + Core" shows the background color being black, but for the rest, it doesn't. I tried doing them separately but nothing works either. I'm assuming its a simple mistake I made somewhere, especially if it works for the "Cardio + Core" button. I also ended up giving each button a number, such as: "btn1", "btn2" etc. Is there a much cleaner way to do this? Especially since I have more buttons on the page.

```css
.heading {
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
    color: #008000;
}

.heading h2 {
    font-weight: 600;
    font-size: 30px;
    color: #008000;
}

.content {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
}

.contentBx {
    padding-right: 30px;
}

.contentBx h3 {
    font-size: 24px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.w50 {
    min-width: 50%;
}

img {
    max-width: 100%;
}

.programs {
    background: black;
}

.heading {
    color: white;
}

.programs .content {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    flex-direction: row;
}

.programs .content .programsBx {
    padding: 40px 20px;
    background: white;
    color: #008000;
    max-width: 340px;
    margin: 20px;
    text-align: center;
    transition: .5s;
}

.programs .content .programsBx:hover {
    background: #008000;
    color: black;
}

.programs .content .programsBx h2 {
    font-size: 20px;
    font-weight: 800;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}


.btn1, .btn2, .btn3, .btn4, .btn5, .btn6, .btn7 {
    position: relative;
    background: black;
    display: inline-block;
    color: #ffffff;
    margin-top: 20px;
    padding: 10px 30px;
    font-size: 18px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    text-decoration: none;
    letter-spacing: 2px;
    font-weight: 700;
    border-radius: 20px;
}

.btn1, .btn2, .btn3, .btn4, .btn5, .btn6, .btn7:hover {
    background: white;
    color: #008000;
}
```

```html
<section class="programs">
        <div class="heading">
            <h2>Programs</h2>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. At, vitae?</p>
        </div>
        <div class="content">
            <div class="programsBx">
                <img src="images/workout (2).png" alt="">
                <h2>Online Training</h2>
                <p>Training sessions with --- facilitated online give you the consistent workouts you want, from the comfort and safety of your own home.</p>
                <a href="#" class="btn1">Enroll Here</a>
            </div>
            <div class="programsBx">
                <img src="images/gymnast.png" alt="">
                <h2>Leg and Glute Toning</h2>
                <p>Muscle tone gives you the strength to back up what you are trying to achieve.

                    There is a big difference between looking slim and looking toned. ---- will design a plan for you to get more toned, and fully explain the workouts that will help you achieve a noticeable change in the next 12 weeks.</p>
                <a href="#" class="btn2">Enroll Here</a>
            </div>
            <div class="programsBx">
                <img src="images/diet.png" alt="">
                <h2>Diet & Transformation</h2>
                <p>Achieve that slim body you always wanted with a 12-week personalized diet plan.

                   --- will tell you exactly what foods to eat and avoid, creating a personalized diet for you based on your specific physical and life conditions. Dexter will fully explain how to execute your meal plan, with quantities and times to eat.</p>
                <a href="#" class="btn3">Enroll Here</a>
            </div>
            <div class="programsBx">
                <img src="images/sports-and-competition.png" alt="">
                <h2>Abs Transformation</h2>
                <p>15 day abs transformation: toning and sculpting mid-section & lower back.

                    This is not for beginners or people with excessive fat at their stomachs. Designed for the person who has been working hard at their abs and needs the last bit of definition they have been craving for: the lines and the super flat lower tummy, without the love handles.</p>
                <a href="#" class="btn4">Enroll Here</a>
            </div>
            <div class="programsBx">
                <img src="images/goal.png" alt="">
                <h2>Achieve Your Dream</h2>
                <p>4 months to make your dream into YOUR achievement with personalized training from ---.

                    Begin the journey to achieve your dream today and find out just how great you can become. Get one-on-one support from --- to learn the mindset, training, nutrition, discipline and daily habits it takes as you progressively achieve your goal over the next 4 months.</p>
                <a href="#" class="btn5">Enroll Here</a>
            </div>
            <div class="programsBx">
                <img src="images/food.png" alt="">
                <h2>Diet Plan Only</h2>
                <p>Perfect your physique in a specific time limit with a day diet plan from Richardo.

                    You’re already fit with an exercise routine that’s working, but your diet needs improvement. A custom daily mean plan for your body will be made, to perfect performance and aesthetics.</p>
                <a href="#" class="btn6">Enroll Here</a>
            </div>
            <div class="programsBx">
                <img src="images/workout (1).png" alt="">
                <h2>Cardio + Core</h2>
                <p>Cardio and core training requires a pattern that truly challenges your body.

                    --- will provide you with a personalized AM/PM cardio and core training plan, fully explaining what you will do every day to execute. Get the right pattern of exercises from Dexter so you see and feel results in 12 weeks.</p>
                <a href="#" class="btn7">Enroll Here</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
```

Comment: You're missing `:hover` on the btn 1-6 classes.

Comment: @DigitalDrifter - Hahaha, I figured it was something very simple. I honestly thought I could've just put ":hover" at the end and it would work for all.

Comment: This question is duplicate...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can simply use `.btn` class for all buttons if u r not adding any specific styles to each button.

or if u want to add specific styles then add some class name to each button.

use `.btn` class for adding common styles to all buttons.

use `.btn1` class to add styles for a specific button.

if you want to add different styles to each button .btn1,.btn2,btn3... like this you can add a class name to all buttons

```css
.heading {
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
    color: #008000;
}

.heading h2 {
    font-weight: 600;
    font-size: 30px;
    color: #008000;
}

.content {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
}

.contentBx {
    padding-right: 30px;
}

.contentBx h3 {
    font-size: 24px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.w50 {
    min-width: 50%;
}

img {
    max-width: 100%;
}

.programs {
    background: black;
}

.heading {
    color: white;
}

.programs .content {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    flex-direction: row;
}

.programs .content .programsBx {
    padding: 40px 20px;
    background: white;
    color: #008000;
    max-width: 340px;
    margin: 20px;
    text-align: center;
    transition: .5s;
}

.programs .content .programsBx:hover {
    background: #008000;
    color: black;
}

.programs .content .programsBx h2 {
    font-size: 20px;
    font-weight: 800;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}


.btn {
    position: relative;
    background: black;
    display: inline-block;
    color: #ffffff;
    margin-top: 20px;
    padding: 10px 30px;
    font-size: 18px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    text-decoration: none;
    letter-spacing: 2px;
    font-weight: 700;
    border-radius: 20px;
}
.btn1{
  background-color:blue;
}
.btn:hover {
    background: white;
    color: #008000;
}
```

```html
<section class="programs">
        <div class="heading">
            <h2>Programs</h2>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. At, vitae?</p>
        </div>
        <div class="content">
            <div class="programsBx">
                <img src="images/workout (2).png" alt="">
                <h2>Online Training</h2>
                <p>Training sessions with --- facilitated online give you the consistent workouts you want, from the comfort and safety of your own home.</p>
                <a href="#" class="btn btn1">Enroll Here</a>
            </div>
            <div class="programsBx">
                <img src="images/gymnast.png" alt="">
                <h2>Leg and Glute Toning</h2>
                <p>Muscle tone gives you the strength to back up what you are trying to achieve.

                    There is a big difference between looking slim and looking toned. ---- will design a plan for you to get more toned, and fully explain the workouts that will help you achieve a noticeable change in the next 12 weeks.</p>
                <a href="#" class="btn btn2">Enroll Here</a>
            </div>
            <div class="programsBx">
                <img src="images/diet.png" alt="">
                <h2>Diet & Transformation</h2>
                <p>Achieve that slim body you always wanted with a 12-week personalized diet plan.

                   --- will tell you exactly what foods to eat and avoid, creating a personalized diet for you based on your specific physical and life conditions. Dexter will fully explain how to execute your meal plan, with quantities and times to eat.</p>
                <a href="#" class="btn btn3">Enroll Here</a>
            </div>
            <div class="programsBx">
                <img src="images/sports-and-competition.png" alt="">
                <h2>Abs Transformation</h2>
                <p>15 day abs transformation: toning and sculpting mid-section & lower back.

                    This is not for beginners or people with excessive fat at their stomachs. Designed for the person who has been working hard at their abs and needs the last bit of definition they have been craving for: the lines and the super flat lower tummy, without the love handles.</p>
                <a href="#" class="btn btn4">Enroll Here</a>
            </div>
            <div class="programsBx">
                <img src="images/goal.png" alt="">
                <h2>Achieve Your Dream</h2>
                <p>4 months to make your dream into YOUR achievement with personalized training from ---.

                    Begin the journey to achieve your dream today and find out just how great you can become. Get one-on-one support from --- to learn the mindset, training, nutrition, discipline and daily habits it takes as you progressively achieve your goal over the next 4 months.</p>
                <a href="#" class="btn btn5">Enroll Here</a>
            </div>
            <div class="programsBx">
                <img src="images/food.png" alt="">
                <h2>Diet Plan Only</h2>
                <p>Perfect your physique in a specific time limit with a day diet plan from Richardo.

                    You’re already fit with an exercise routine that’s working, but your diet needs improvement. A custom daily mean plan for your body will be made, to perfect performance and aesthetics.</p>
                <a href="#" class="btn btn6">Enroll Here</a>
            </div>
            <div class="programsBx">
                <img src="images/workout (1).png" alt="">
                <h2>Cardio + Core</h2>
                <p>Cardio and core training requires a pattern that truly challenges your body.

                    --- will provide you with a personalized AM/PM cardio and core training plan, fully explaining what you will do every day to execute. Get the right pattern of exercises from Dexter so you see and feel results in 12 weeks.</p>
                <a href="#" class="btn btn7">Enroll Here</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
```

Comment: Yeah, I actually have more than one buttons on that page that I have different styles for, so I had to number them unfortunately ;-;

Comment: now check out my answer @RojiE

Comment: Oohh, I see what you did. I didn't think of that tbh, makes sense and its much cleaner. Its funny how there's so many ways this can be done, and much simpler than how I did it.

Answer (score 2):

**You can use single .btn class for buttons and manage their hover state with their parent class.**

```css
body {
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}
.heading {
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
    color: #008000;
}

.heading h2 {
    font-weight: 600;
    font-size: 30px;
    color: #008000;
    margin:0;
    padding: 10px 0;
}

.content {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
}

.contentBx {
    padding-right: 30px;
}

.contentBx h3 {
    font-size: 24px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.w50 {
    min-width: 50%;
}

img {
    max-width: 100%;
}

.programs {
    background: black;
}

.heading {
    color: white;
}

.programs .content {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    flex-direction: row;
}

.programs .content .programsBx {
    padding: 40px 20px;
    background: white;
    color: #008000;
    max-width: 340px;
    margin: 20px;
    text-align: center;
    transition: .5s;
}

.programs .content .programsBx:hover {
    background: #008000;
    color: black;
}

.programs .content .programsBx h2 {
    font-size: 20px;
    font-weight: 800;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}


.programsBx .btn {
    position: relative;
    background-color: black;
    display: inline-block;
    color: #ffffff;
    margin-top: 20px;
    padding: 10px 30px;
    font-size: 18px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    text-decoration: none;
    letter-spacing: 2px;
    font-weight: 700;
    border-radius: 20px;
}

.programsBx:hover .btn {
    background: white;
    color: #008000;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
    <title>Document</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <section class="programs">
      <div class="heading">
        <h2>Programs</h2>
        <p>
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. At, vitae?
        </p>
      </div>
      <div class="content">
        <div class="programsBx">
          <img src="images/workout (2).png" alt="" />
          <h2>Online Training</h2>
          <p>
            Training sessions with --- facilitated online give you the
            consistent workouts you want, from the comfort and safety of your
            own home.
          </p>
          <a href="#" class="btn">Enroll Here</a>
        </div>
        <div class="programsBx">
          <img src="images/gymnast.png" alt="" />
          <h2>Leg and Glute Toning</h2>
          <p>
            Muscle tone gives you the strength to back up what you are trying to
            achieve. There is a big difference between looking slim and looking
            toned. ---- will design a plan for you to get more toned, and fully
            explain the workouts that will help you achieve a noticeable change
            in the next 12 weeks.
          </p>
          <a href="#" class="btn">Enroll Here</a>
        </div>
        <div class="programsBx">
          <img src="images/diet.png" alt="" />
          <h2>Diet & Transformation</h2>
          <p>
            Achieve that slim body you always wanted with a 12-week personalized
            diet plan. --- will tell you exactly what foods to eat and avoid,
            creating a personalized diet for you based on your specific physical
            and life conditions. Dexter will fully explain how to execute your
            meal plan, with quantities and times to eat.
          </p>
          <a href="#" class="btn">Enroll Here</a>
        </div>
        <div class="programsBx">
          <img src="images/sports-and-competition.png" alt="" />
          <h2>Abs Transformation</h2>
          <p>
            15 day abs transformation: toning and sculpting mid-section & lower
            back. This is not for beginners or people with excessive fat at
            their stomachs. Designed for the person who has been working hard at
            their abs and needs the last bit of definition they have been
            craving for: the lines and the super flat lower tummy, without the
            love handles.
          </p>
          <a href="#" class="btn">Enroll Here</a>
        </div>
        <div class="programsBx">
          <img src="images/goal.png" alt="" />
          <h2>Achieve Your Dream</h2>
          <p>
            4 months to make your dream into YOUR achievement with personalized
            training from ---. Begin the journey to achieve your dream today and
            find out just how great you can become. Get one-on-one support from
            --- to learn the mindset, training, nutrition, discipline and daily
            habits it takes as you progressively achieve your goal over the next
            4 months.
          </p>
          <a href="#" class="btn">Enroll Here</a>
        </div>
        <div class="programsBx">
          <img src="images/food.png" alt="" />
          <h2>Diet Plan Only</h2>
          <p>
            Perfect your physique in a specific time limit with a day diet plan
            from Richardo. You’re already fit with an exercise routine that’s
            working, but your diet needs improvement. A custom daily mean plan
            for your body will be made, to perfect performance and aesthetics.
          </p>
          <a href="#" class="btn">Enroll Here</a>
        </div>
        <div class="programsBx">
          <img src="images/workout (1).png" alt="" />
          <h2>Cardio + Core</h2>
          <p>
            Cardio and core training requires a pattern that truly challenges
            your body. --- will provide you with a personalized AM/PM cardio and
            core training plan, fully explaining what you will do every day to
            execute. Get the right pattern of exercises from Dexter so you see
            and feel results in 12 weeks.
          </p>
          <a href="#" class="btn">Enroll Here</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Ohh, that makes sense. Placing it inside of the parent class so the other's aren't affected. Alright, I'll do that, it'll make my code much cleaner for sure, thank you !

Comment: @AmareshSM If, I am not getting it wrong. that was the requirement as you hover over the card button color should change from black to white.

Answer (score 1):

Your CSS is messed up on the `:hover` selector. Use this:

```
.btn1:hover, .btn2:hover, .btn3:hover, .btn4:hover, .btn5:hover, .btn6:hover, .btn7:hover {
    background: white;
    color: #008000;
}
```

Comment: Yes, this works. But, is there another way it could work without the code being that lengthy? Preciate it!!

Comment: Make a generic button class and apply it to all of your button links. `.btn`, `.btn:hover`

Comment: You could make it cleaner if you use SCSS or LESS

Comment: Alright, I'll do that, good looking out!